# React State Undefined

Tags: reactjs, express, react-redux, redux-thunk, mern

The problem is that when I first Logged-in, The userId Variable on renderList() or the this.props.user will always be null. it will work when I refreshed it. I tried checking it on the first line of renderList function but it seems it will always be null after I logged in. I even tried to dispatch the fetchBlog actions before redirecting after logging in successfully.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { fetchBlogs, deleteBlog } from '../../actions';

class FetchBlogs extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchBlogs();
    }


    renderButtons(blog, userId){
        if(blog._id = userId){
            return (
                <div>
                    <Button as={Link} to={`/blogs/edit/${blog._id}`} className="mx-2" variant="outline-warning" size="md">Edit</Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => {
                    this.props.deleteBlog(blog._id)
                    }}
                    className="mx-2" 
                    variant="outline-danger" 
                    size="md">
                        Delete
                    </Button>
                </div>
            );
        }
        return '';
    }

    renderList(){
        const userId = this.props.user && this.props.user._id;
        return this.props.blogs.map(blog => {
            return (
                <Card className="m-2" key={blog.title}>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title as={Link} to={`/blogs/${blog._id}`}>{blog.title}</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text>{blog.content}</Card.Text>
                    </Card.Body>
                    <div className="mb-2">
                        {this.renderButtons(blog, userId)}
                    </div>
                </Card>
            );
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 className="m-2">My Blogs</h2>
                {this.renderList()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const stateToProps = state => {
    return {
        blogs: Object.values(state.blogs),
        user: state.auth.user,
    }
}

export default connect(stateToProps, { fetchBlogs, deleteBlog, })(FetchBlogs);
```

This is the code for my action login

```
export const login = formValues => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        header: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    try{
        const res = await portfolios.post('/auth/login', formValues, config)
        dispatch({
            type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
            payload: res.data
        });

        dispatch(fetchBlogs())
        history.push('/blogs/all');
    }catch(e){
        dispatch({
            type: 'LOGIN_FAILED',
        });
        history.push('/auth/login');
    }
}
```

This is my Auth Reducer

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    access: localStorage.getItem('access'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    isLoading: false,
    user: null,
}


const authReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
        case 'REGISTER_SUCCESS':
            localStorage.setItem("access", action.payload.token);
            return {
                ...state,
                access: action.payload.token,
                user: action.payload.user,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                isLoading: false
            };
        case 'AUTH_ERROR':
        case 'LOGIN_FAILED':
        case 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS':
        case 'REGISTER_FAIL':
            localStorage.removeItem('access');
            return {
                ...state,
                user: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                isLoading: false,
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I don't know what am I missing. Ive checked and Searched some answers and I did check if the prop is null but still no changes

Comment: What and where is the code that is setting or updating `state.auth.user` such that it is defined in state *after* any initial render? Either wait to render `FetchBlogs` component until the `user` state is defined, or implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method in `FetchBlogs` so `fetchBlogs` is dispatched when `user` updates. When do you want `fetchBlogs` dispatched?

Comment: when I logged in successfully. that is when state.auth will be populated. first the element user is null but after log in if its successfull. state.auth.user will be populated with the user's information from database using token. I only call the fetchblogs from the componentDidMount() also when the I successfully logged in from the action file.

Comment: Is `FetchBlogs` component mounted and rendered when you log in?

Comment: const res = await portfolios.post('/auth/login', formValues, config)
        dispatch({
            type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
            payload: res.data
        });

        dispatch(fetchBlogs())
        history.push('/blogs/all');
that is my code when I loggedin successfully.

Comment: shoot. im sorry i dont know how to format the code to make it readable.

Comment: No worries, comments aren't really for code, just update your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: I already Edited it. thank you by the way.

Comment: I think the navigation is occurring *before* the reducers update state. Are you running *some* asynchronous redux middleware, or is this a login function on another page? Think you could try to create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I think I already solved it. I created a loadUser action and dispatch it after i logged in successfully. thank you so much for the clue.